# Has the Borg's technology ever been shown to advance?

Tags: star-trek, borg

The whole idea of the Borg is that they're in a constant state of assimilation and improvement. However, has there ever been any point in the franchise where the Borg were shown to have become more technologically advanced than they were earlier? Unlike, say, The Federation, I've never gotten the impression that the technology of the Borg has improved between their introduction and any later point in the franchise.

Comment: good catch, even in all their prequel appearances in Enterprise they seem pretty much as they are throughout basically the entire franchise // the only change that does appear to be tracked in their tech throughout their appearances in the franchise is their warp drive tech // I've not seen the new Picard films yet though.

Comment: The Borg cube in Picard seems to be significantly more advanced than any Borg vessel or station we have seen in other Trek series....  Does that count?

Comment: @Pelinore the Borg from Enterprise were from the 24th century, having traveled back in time during the events of First Contact and left deactivated until researchers found them at the start of the episode. We never see 22nd century Borg.

Comment: @PrincessAda the Regeneration episode yes, [does a little quick Googling], [ponders results], I thought I remembered another was that the only appearance? meh, getting old, my memory may be sprained :)

Comment: I think the question misses the mark on the Borg's traits. They don't have the imagination or ingenuity to drastically improve their own technology, if any Borg were to show signs of this individuality, they would be terminated. The Borg's improvements occurred by assimilating other civilizations individuals and technology. The lack of significant improvements to the Borg technology is evidence that they never encountered civilizations with technology better than them.

Comment: The Borg are shown on multiple instances to change shield frequencies or do other things to negate Federation weapons as well as find new ways to penetrate Federation shields mid-battle, which would be forms of technology advancement. They might not be massive leaps, but new information and techniques are still advancement.

Comment: Answer:  To the extent that the Borg only assimilate races that have biological and technological distinction, any time they assimilitate a new race, it's **advancement** from their perspective.    So every time we need a newly assimilated race, including, arguably, humans, Vulcans, Romulans and other alpha/beta quadrant races, this is implicit "technological advancement" from their perspective.

Comment: @computercarguy I assumed "adapting to energy frequencies" was a skill they always had (they do it slowly since they're basically space zombies). It's like when a cat learns to open a particular door. That can be a big change; but it's not new in general -- door opening is existing cat technology.

Comment: @OwenReynolds, it may be that lots of cats can open doors, but they aren't mind linked to share the info, nor do they usually learn this from other cats even in the same neighborhood, so that's not really a good analogy. Also, I said it wasn't a major advancement, but any new knowledge, such as learning what frequency changes blocks Federation weapons, is a type of advancement. Me learning a new computer language isn't an advancement in tech for the industry, but it is an advancement for me, and depending on how similar it is to others I already know, it might not be much of an advancement.

Comment: They would only advance if the technology is sufficiently superior to their current technology. Seeing how they are already very advanced, they wouldn't be adding superior technology very often. Also assimilating entire cultures would take a long time, they wouldn't be assimilating new cultures frequently during the time years we see them in Star Trek.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

One example that comes to mind is the assimilation tubules. When the Borg are first shown to assimilate Captain Picard in the episode "The Best of Both Worlds", they have to take him over to their ship and carry out a medical procedure. Throughout *The Next Generation* TV series there is no indication that they have any other means by which to assimilate individuals.

Then in the second *TNG* movie *First Contact* the Borg are shown to possess "assimilation tubules", devices that can reach out from the wrist of any Borg drone to inject nearby victims with Borg nanoprobes and assimilate them in a matter of seconds. From this point on drones are a much bigger threat as they can quickly multiply. This goes on to be standard Borg procedure when they return in *Star Trek: Voyager*.

Comment: I think this is the more solid answer. This is tech that is fully assimilated and spread out to all the borg, unlike the other answer.

Comment: @WolfieSmith - except that there is no confirmation that this change actually occurred in-universe. This, along with more complicated patterning on their ships, appears to simply have been as a result of better CGI

Comment: To add to that, I recall an episode of Enterprise with an old crashed and buried Borg ship. When the drones woke up they quickly infected the unfortunate researches with "wrist vines", even though it was hundreds of years before Picard met them.

Comment: @Owen the Borg ship in Enterprise was from the 24th century, and came back during ST:First Contact.

Comment: I agree with @Valorum.  I think the tubules were more of a retcon than an in-universe technological advancement.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: Somehow, it's astonishingly easy to forget that the entire idea of the Borg as a mass-assimilating horde was not yet present during TNG and only retconned in as of First Contact.

Comment: @Mapper they tried to assimilate the Enterprise for its tech in their first appearance ("The Borg are the ultimate user. They're unlike any threat your Federation has ever faced. They're not interested in political conquest, wealth, or power as you know it. They're simply interested in your ship, its technology. They've identified it as something they can consume." -Q), and they succeeded in assimilating Picard in their second.

Comment: The Borg Queen in *First Contact* also seems to represent a major advance (or at least significant change) in their technology.

Comment: @WolfieSmith And during that encounter they ignored the people on the ship.  Whether it was a retcon or an in-universe change, there was definitely a change.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Interestingly, the Borg were apparently originally intended to be insectoid (cut due to budget constraints), and later the result of the parasite from Conspiracy. In either case, the whole point was slow, lumbering, implacable (and for the parasite idea, very good at infiltration). The Borg from First Contact on are ridiculously different, little more than boring space zombies.

Comment: Consider the dramatic difference between a Borg cube parked above a world for potentially years converting people surgically with nothing able to stop it.  Nanobots in theory would behave like any zombie apocalypse virus.  Sneak a single drone onto a world and convert everyone.  This is one of First Contact's many logic failures.

Answer (score 27):

Although there are various minor instances of the Borg adapting to various efforts made by Picard and Janeway to attack them, a really solid example of technological progress is the Borg's acquisition of the [Spatial Trajector](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Spatial_trajector) from the Sikarians seen in Voyager.

Comment: Didn't they also acquire tech to assimilate people without the complicated machinery seen in their debut episode?

Comment: @Medinoc - they appear to have done, but I personally just ascribe it to improved CGI. Certainly it is never mentioned in the shows

Answer (score 8):

The Voyager episode [Drone](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Drone_(episode)) is about a transporter mishap that causes one of Seven's nanoprobes to interact with the Doctor's mobile emitter, a piece of technology from the 29th century. The nanoprobes extrapolate various future technologies and materials from the device and create a significantly more advanced Borg drone than normal in the 24th century. *(This drone is sometimes refered to as a "29th century Borg drone", but it's strictly speaking a 24th century Borg drone that has had access to 29th century technology.)*

While this is not an example of the Borg *developing* over time, it does show that they do indeed have the **capability** to develop over time as they assimilate new technologies and integrate them into drones, should they come across them.

As to why Borg development doesn't seem to happen over the course of the series, here's one possible explanation:

In the Voyager episode Scorpion, it is stated that the Borg don't perform research*; all their knowledge is gained through assimilations of other cultures. As such, major technological improvements would presumably only occur whenever they manage to come across and assimilate a species with some piece of technology more advanced than their own, with is presumably a rare occurrence given how much technology they already have access to. By the 24th century, it's not inconceivable that the Borg development has effectively plateaued.

*) Though this may simply be an assertion on B'elanna's part. Later statements about the Borg performing experiments on Omega seem to contradict this somewhat.

Comment: Excellent point. I would have to dig deep in the attic, but i vaguely recall having read something somewhere years and years ago - might have been the *First Contact* (movie not episode) novelization (but admittedly could easily have been some fanfic) - that this plateau was one of the reasons the Queen had in *First Contact* in trying to assimilate Data and through him to reassimilate Picard. Because why else would the Borg be interested in the Federation - inferior technology, yet a determination to grow and evolve the Borg are lacking...

Answer (score 3):

In the TV Series Picard:

> Within the captured Borg Cube, Hugh points out several advances to Picard, which have been created since Picard had last seen the Borg tech

Comment: You could improve this answer by citing one or more specific examples of their improved tech. Posting an exact quote would be beneficial too.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I had recently seen it, but not noticed it referenced above so I felt it should be mentioned. 
However, when I have checked further, I can see that this is already better answered by @valorum above.